# Lua if returns false but should return true

Tags: lua

So I have this piece of code

```
 for i=1, #result, 1 do

            local vehicleProps = json.decode(result[i].vehicle)
            print(vehicleProps.plate)
            print(plate)

            if vehicleProps.plate == plate then
                found = true
                print(found)
                break
            end
            print(found)

        end
```

The output I get is

```
UCF 804 
864539 
false 
65507 
864539 
false 
864539 
864539 
false
```

I am fairly new to Lua, but it is pretty simple, yet I cannot understand why when vehicleProps.plate is equal to plate, the code returns false?
Is there any way to check if two values are the same?
I would appreaciate any type of help here.

Output for user: hjpotter92

```
2162899082 417849 string string false 
QBW 339 417849 string string false 
27538 417849 string string false 
UCF 804 417849 string string false 
417849 417849 string string false 
65507 417849 string string false 
864539 417849 string string false 
9703143430 417849 string string false
```

Comment: Are you comparing a number with a string by any chance?

Comment: Both are strings

Comment: Is it possible you have non-visible char at the end of the string? such as `\r`

Comment: you can print multiple items in a single call. `print(vehicleProps.plate, plate, type(vehicleProps.plate), type(plate), vehicleProps.plate == plate)` and check (possibly edit the question with output of this?)

Comment: @hjpotter92 done

Comment: @Nifim I am not sure honestly.. might be possible, any way I can check?

Comment: I believe what you just did for @hjpotter92 would have revealed if there were non-visible chars.

Comment: follow up questions, which `json` library is this? and which lua version?

Comment: ~Shot in the dark, can you try flipping the statement to `plate == vehicleProps.plate`. If there is a `metatable` at work on `vehicleProps.plate` this should use the basic compare.~ sorry that would only be if both had the same metamethod

Comment: Might also be because of leading/trailing whitespaces. You can try printing length of both strings too: `print(#plate, #(vehicleProps.plate))`

Answer (score 1):

```
function all_trim(s)
                        return s:match( "^%s*(.-)%s*$" )
                    end
                if all_trim(vehicleProps.plate) == all_trim(plate) then
```

Edited my code to be as follows,
Looks like there was a space in there afterall, thank you everybody for trying to help

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer, so it will show resolved, thanks.